# SSRS randomly gets error for parameter - solution is to rebuild report...then it happens again

Tags: reporting-services

I am pretty experienced in SSRS, I have been doing it for quite some time so I know when I see the error:

"An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
An attempt was made to set a data set parameter '@SiteId' that is not defined in this data set. (rsUnknownDataSetParameter)"

I know what causes this error and can fix it.  However, this error randomly happens every so often.  What I end up doing is simply rebuilding the project and redeploying it and all is well for a few days, then suddenly again this same error will pop up again.

I know there is no issue with the parameter as I have a @SiteId parameter as shown:

[image]

So when I get an email from a user that "The Report Is Down" I just go to my report and rebuild and republish and the error vanishes without ANY other changes.  A few days later when they want to run the report again this same error happens.  What is causing this issue to come back over and over.  We are running SQL Server 2016 with SSRS.  It happens to ANY one of my reports on the report server.  Its not a specific project it randomly happens on any project.

**EDIT**

What I did notice does happen is when a user reports this issue I go to the "Manage" of a report on the report server url.  This area is where you find the properties, data sources, and parameters.  When I click parameters I see this error:

[image]

So obviously something is destroying the parameters - that is where I am confused what is causing that.  This is probably why I am getting the error message.  So to reiterate a report is published works...suddenly the parameters go missing.  User reports "the report no longer works" I rebuild and redeploy the report...it then works again for a day or so maybe more than a day I never investigated how long it takes for it to break again (as these are not urgent reports).  Days later user says report is dead again...if I go to the report server using the report server url and click "Manage" and then click "Parameters" for some reason the parameters have disappeared...causing me to yet again redeploy.  This happens over and over and over.  It never ends...

Comment: That is very strange. Are you using a stored procedure for your dataset?

Comment: @Diego - Yes I am using a stored procedure, and this dataset (at least for the Sites from the picture above) is a shared dataset calling a sproc.  I reuse this dataset across a lot of my reports because its common for site names we have.

Comment: I just noticed your edit. Are the parameters appearing in the Dataset Properties?

Comment: @Diego I wanted to tell you see my edit...So something is destroyting these parameters daily.  Like if I rebuild the report and republish they are there...if i wait a few days and then check the parameters they suddenly disappear.  See my edit in the question showing you the error.

Comment: Yeah this is weird. I was able to recreate this error by removing my parameters from the Parameters tab in the Dataset Properties. Make sure that your parameters are in there and that they match the case and spelling in your stored procedure. If that doesn't work I would declare the variables in the stored procedure and assign it to the parameter used in reporting services, `declare @localSiteId datatype = @SiteId` and then make sure to change the `@SiteId` in the query to `@localSiteId`

Comment: Do other people work on reports? Based on Diego's comments, is it possible somebody else is deploying reports and is overwriting your shared dataset? It would be interesting to take a copy of ReportServer.dbo.Catalog compare from just after you deploy against when the user reports it being broken again.

Comment: Also take a copy of dbo.DataSets. I "think", if the dataset gets overwritten then it will get a new ID. dbo.DataSets stores the links between reports and datasets. ItemID is the ID of the Report in dbo.Catalog and ID is the ItemID of the dataset in dbo.Catalog . If these change, it would suggest the dataset is being overwritten.

Comment: No one else has access to build reports.

Comment: it might be an idea to take copies of these tables for comparison though even if it's just to eliminate the dataset getting updated somehow.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - The datasets are all there - where are the parameters stored ?

Comment: @Diego - I dont think creating local variables is the issue, the issue is SSRS maybe in the XML I dont know the parameters are being deleted.  Remember you yourself mentioned you reproduced it by deleting the parameters directly in the reporting services management page (their portal).  So declaring them as local parameters help me in no way as the report doesnt have the parameter at all...This is seriously bugging me.  I will place a bounty tomorrow but I have tried everything.  Does anyone know if the parameters are stored in a table in SSRS db ?

Comment: @JonH - there is a Parameter field in the Catalog table in the ReportServer db.

Comment: @HannoverFist - Ya I see it and it looks right.  I am puzzled

Comment: I think we all agreed that this is nothing we have seen before. If it were me, as I said before, I would take a copy of the catalog and datasets tables when the reports are working, and then again as soon as they break. Comparing them 'may' help you focus on anything that has changed but beyond that I'm not sure what else to say...

Comment: @AlanSchofield - I can do that but what Im saying is that was sort of done already.  The querying of the data is the same between the old and new...as an example: `SELECT 
 c.Name,
 c2.Name,
 c2.Parameter
FROM 
 DataSets d 
INNER JOIN
 [Catalog] c
ON
 c.ItemID = d.ItemID
INNER JOIN
 [Catalog] c2
ON
 c2.ItemID = d.LinkID
WHERE
 --one specific report for now
 d.ItemID='6c2858bb-1f38-4154-9826-bcc39747cc5d'` reviewing this when I publish a good version vs when it broke is the same.  Nothing has changed in these tables.  Please note for simplicity im only pulling a few columns.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - Holy cow I see the issue, I will explain in a bit I want to thank Alan because I did find one difference that I overlooked I will post an answer in a bit I just have to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short of it is you cannot have the same shared dataset name across different SSRS Projects that are on the same SSRS server.**

So within our SSRS "repository" we have several different SSRS projects.  Both projects are very specific to certain functionality.  What I noticed is everytime I deployed one of these SSRS projects the reports on the other project would stop working.

When the email would come from the user stating Application A's reports werent working I'd go to Application A's SSRS project and redeploy it and it would fix the issue.  Days later a different user said Application B's reports weren't working so I would redeploy application B's.  Not knowing that when I deployed A's reports B's would break, and vice versa deploying B's broke A's.

Come to find out....both projects had a shared dataset with the SAME NAME (dsEmployees).  Same name however these datasets pointed to different sprocs with different parameters.  Well when you deploy and look at the back end db the `Catalog` table only has one entry for dsEmployees.  Everytime I redeployed this would overwrite with the other dataset since the names were the same.

Lesson learned across different SSRS projects be careful with the shared dataset name, they must be different.  I was able to spot the difference by running the following query:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name,
    c2.*,
    c2.Parameter
FROM 
    DataSets d 
INNER JOIN
    [Catalog] c
ON
    c.ItemID = d.ItemID
INNER JOIN
    [Catalog] c2
ON
    c2.ItemID = d.LinkID
WHERE
    --one specific report for now
    d.ItemID='C3008EF4-E544-48F3-92C1-2222C6148B13'
```

When the report was stated not to work.  Then I would redeploy the report and rerun that sql statement I wrote and dumped the rows to an excel sheet to compare.  One of those columns is `Parameters` and I noticed the parameters were slightly different.  Immediately I was onto something and this ended up being it.  Thanks to comment posted it helped me relook at this!  This has bugged me for years!

Comment: Glad you resolved it. I didn't think about duplicate dataset names although I did know that they are shared by name, the default deployment from VS is that shared datasets (and datasources) are not overwritten by default for exactly this reason. At least this only bugged me for a day! :)

Comment: @AlanSchofield you would think they would uniquely identify dataset names and not key off the text?  I know there is an item id but if you have one dataset called dsEmployees in one project and the same named one in another deploying it would overwrite it. To me that isnt good and hence this happened to me. I should of known better and searched a little bit more.